# How to filter data from multiple nested documents / multiple child documents from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is a sample document that I am trying on

```
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "description" : "DESCRIPTION ARTICLE AD",
    "article_code" : "AD",
    "purchase" : [
        {
            "company" : 1,
            "cost" : "70.010000"
        },
        {
            "company" : 2,
            "cost" : "75.820000"
        },
        {
            "company" : 3,
            "cost" : "69.910000"
        }
    ],
    "stock" : [
        {
            "country" : "01",
            "warehouse" : {
                "code" : "01",
                "units" : 5
            }
        },
        {
            "country" : "01",
            "warehouse" : {
                "code" : "02",
                "units" : 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My use case is we have documents containing multiple objects like stock and purchase, userInfo, lang user speaks etc etc. I am applying criteria to get userInfo where username is abc and user role is admin etc . if not matched simply ignore for that particular criteria.

I want to get below output where purchase.company =2 and stocks.warehouse.units = 6.

Sample OP1 ->

```
    "_id" : "3",
    "description" : "DESCRIPTION ARTICLE AD",
    "article_code" : "AD",
    "purchase" : [

        {
            "company" : 2,
            "cost" : "75.820000"
        }
    ],
    "stock" : [
        {
            "country" : "01",
            "warehouse" : {
                "code" : "02",
                "units" : 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample OP2 ->

```
    "_id" : "3",
    "description" : "DESCRIPTION ARTICLE AD",
    "article_code" : "AD",
    "purchase" : [

        {
            "company" : 2,
            "cost" : "75.820000"
        }
    ],
    "stock" : [
        {
            "country" : "01",
            "warehouse" : {
                "units" : 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongodb's [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for this.

```js
db.testdb.aggregate([
  {$match: {"purchase.company": 2 , "stock.warehouse.units" : 6}},
    { $project: {
    _id: 1,
    description: 1,
    article_code: 1,
    purchase: { $filter: {
      input: "$purchase",
      as: "purchase",
      cond: { $eq: ["$$purchase.company", 2] } } },
    stock: { $filter: {
      input: "$stock",
      as: "stock",
      cond: { $eq: ["$$stock.warehouse.units", 6] } } }
  } }
]).pretty()
```

If you execute the query above, the output will be:

```json
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "description" : "DESCRIPTION ARTICLE AD",
    "article_code" : "AD",
    "purchase" : [
        {
            "company" : 2,
            "cost" : "75.820000"
        }
    ],
    "stock" : [
        {
            "country" : "01",
            "warehouse" : {
                    "code" : "02",
                    "units" : 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```